# Discussing Ideas on Math.SE

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Lets say, one has a great Idea, for some proof, some theory or anything by that path. For non-scientists (and even true scientists), it can be hard to get heard. One great thing is posting it on the internet; However, there are few places where these Ideas can be posted and discussed in a reasonable manner.

My **Question** is: Is Math.SE a reasonable place to do so? If yes, how should one formulate his Idea? I have asked about if my Idea was "well-defined" and "reasonable" but I'm not sure if that isn't too vague? 
Should the "Answer your own Question" checkbox be set for these?

If Math.SE is the wrong place for this, are there other places where ones voice can be heard? In many cases, posts have been closed because they were no question -  reasonable, since this is a Q&A site; However, are there any I&D (Idea and discussion) or C&D (Claim and discussion) pages?

Comment: You have the chat (although it is plagued by off-topic) and you can always start a blog. It's hard to force people to hear you out, but it is even harder if you are using the wrong platform.

Comment: @AsafKaragila So in your opinion, Math.SE is the "wrong platform"?
I agree with the statement that it is hard to "force" people to hear you out; Starting a blog is probably the wrong thing to start with, as noone will read it as long as it doesnt get any attention.

Comment: Yes. Math.SE is not suitable for discussions. If you have a specific question about the development of your idea, it could be fine. You could write a longer question explaining the relevant parts of this idea, and ask if there are any anticipated problems. However you will have to give some very good motivations in order to attract people to think about such new idea seriously. Just posting an idea and asking for a discussion is an invitation for closing votes...

Comment: Your profile says that you are a 19 years old maths student. I recommend that you start to discuss your ideas with your friends among the other students and with your professors. This has the advantage that you can use your social capital acquired during your study to be heard and that you can read the body language of your audience. If you don't have social capital, start accumulating it (i.e. make good presentations in seminars, listen to others' idea and advice, find teachers that have a compatible personality, ...).

Comment: @Phira I do, just fyi :D Im not really talking about me, just in general. In many cases my Ideas (again, check my profile ^.^) were so wierd not even my professors and assistants had a clue ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, math.SE is not a good place to discuss ideas. I agree with both [Asaf](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6863/discussing-ideas-on-math-se#comment24842_6863) and [Phira's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6863/discussing-ideas-on-math-se#comment24871_6863) comments.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions then?

Comment: @CBenni Both EFnet and Freenode have some fairly active #math channels on IRC. Those might be a good place.

Answer (score 7):

Asking questions about your great ideas is fine, but keep the following FAQ advice in mind:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

If you have already worked out your idea and want to publish it, then MSE is the wrong place. However, if you have thought a bit about a certain idea and want to know more, or want to learn where your idea fits into the big picture, then asking a question on MSE can be quite useful. The challenge is to come up with a reasonably scoped question such that others can help you effectively without spending too much of their valuable time. It might help indeed to first discuss your ideas with your friends among the other students and with your professors.